# Detecting device on Network?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to detect when a device is connected to a PHYSICAL network ? The device may not attempt to make any connection. The intend is detect any device that can potentially do a DOS attack. The focus is ONLY on wired connection and not wireless in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is , only if LLDP is enabled .
LLDP ( Link Layer Discovery Protocol ) discovers neighbors in a network .
CDP ( Cisco Discover Protocol ) similar to LLDP used for only cisco equipements .
you can see more about LLDP and CDP here : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol